# Do we say "late for bed and late for rise" or "late to bed and late to rise"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I saw this phrase "**Why Late to Bed and Late to Rise Can Make You Successful**" from [an online article](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/284714)

Here are my studies

First, normally, we say "**I am late for school/work...**"

Second, we say "**it's time for bed**"

Third, the verb "**rise**" means "**get up**", so the phrase "**late to bed**" and "**late to rise**" don't share similar structure because "**bed**" is a noun and "**rise**" is a verb. "**Rise**" is also a noun but it doesn't have the meaning of "**getting up**".

Do we say "**you are always late for bed and late for rise**" or "**you are always late to bed and late to rise**" or "**you are always late to go to bed and late to rise**"?

Comment: You can also be "late **to** work"; using *to* is fine there, you don't have to say *for*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a play on the common proverb

> Early to bed and early to rise makes and man healthy, wealthy and wise

(https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/early-to-bed-and-early-to-rise.html)

so you can't really  ask if "late" is used properly.

The article is making an argument that although the proverb might be true for most people there are some who do better as night owls

(A night owl is a person who is active late at night, from the same source.)

Comment: The typo comes from the website - it should read _makes a man_, of course.